# How does UNIX allocate space for file on disk after N write operation?

Tags: file, unix, operating-system, diskspace

Assume that you need to perform N=5000 writing operations on disk and each of them fills exactly one block. Each block can store 1024byte so that it can store 256 4-byte pointers.

Besides, assume that the i-node of the file has:

- 13 pointers to data blocks
- 1 pointer to single indirect indirection block
- 1 pointer to double indirect indirection block
- 1 pointer to triple indirect indirection block

How many blocks (among data and indirection) will be used to perform the 5000 writing operation?

**My solution**:

At first UNIX will store 13 blocks using the 13 pointers-to-data-block. Now `N = 5000-13 = 4987`.

Then UNIX uses the following 256 blocks pointed by the index block (accessed by single indirect indirection). So `N = 4987-256 = 4731`.

Then UNIX will use double indirection. It will need `4731 / 256 = 19` (approximated by excess) blocks of single indirect indirection accessed via double indirect indirection. Among these, the first 18 will have all pointers pointing to data block, while the 19th, will only have the first `4731 % 256 = 123` pointers defined.

As a result, the total numbers of blocks allocated will be:

```
13 + 1 + 256 + 1 + 19 + 256*18 + 123 = 5021
```

**BUT**

I know that UNIX allocates blocks in numbers multiple of 16. So, instead of allocating only 19 blocks of single indirection, it will allocate 32 blocks of single indirection (+13). Besides, instead of allocating 123 block of data, UNIX will allocate 128 (+5).

As a result, the total numbers of block allocated will be:

```
5021 + 13 + 5 = 5039
```

Can you please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: *I know that UNIX allocates blocks in numbers multiple of 16* How do you know that?  There's no operating system called "UNIX", although there are several that meet the UNIX *standard*.

Comment: An interesting puzzle, but a meaningful comment is way above my pay grade. I do agree with above comment in that its very likely different unix implementations will handle this case in different ways. I think the best you can so is instrument your test in a way that you can capture size info at various levels and try running that on as many unix implementations you can get. Will be happy to be proved wrong and that there is a way to "know" this with certainty. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunatly I do not have the competence and the know-how to discover the behind the scene by myself. This was a question my Operating-System instructor asked in a past test. Anyway, thanks to both of you for the time you've spent in reading my question.

Comment: So your instructor was claiming that there was one, unambiguously correct answer to this problem? It seems like you have justified your thinking. Didn't s/he correct your error? If not, that is sad state of instruction. But, such is life ;-) . Good luck!

Comment: Well, I asked for clarification to my istructor. He told me that the problem is referred to a Unix-Like operating system which answers to @Andrew_Henie but, yes, it seems that he thinks there's an unumbiguous solution.